# Docker performances for getting information: polling vs events

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have Docker swarm full of containers. I need to monitor when something is up or down. I can do this in 2 ways:

- attaching to the swarm and listen to events.
- polling service list

The issue with events is that there might be huge traffic, plus if some event is not processed, we will simply loose information on whats going on.

For me it is not super important to get immediate results, but to have correct information on whats going on.

Any pros/cons from real-life project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listening to events- its immediate, but risky as if your event listening program crashes because of any reason, you will miss an important information and lead to wrong result. This [Registrator](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator/) program is based on events.
Polling- eventual consistent result. but if it solves your problem it is less painful way to grabbing the data. No matter if your program crashes or restart. We are using this approach for service discovery in our project and so far it served the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, checking if something is up or down should be done using a health check, and should be agnostic to the underlying architecture running your service (otherwise you will have to write a new health check every time you change platform). Of course - you might have services with specific needs that cannot be monitored that way - if this is the case you're welcome to comment on that.

If you are using Swarm for stateless services only, I suggest creating a health check route that can verify the service is healthy and even disconnect faulty containers from the service.

If you are running statefull stuff this might be trickier, but there are solutions for that too, usually using some kind of monitoring agent over your statefull container (We are using cloudwatch since we run on AWS, but there are many alternatives)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, I totally understand what you are saying, we do similar thing. However, I am interested here in stability/performance differences for some other reasons. Thanx!